# How to maintain state in Fitnesse tests with c# Fitnesse+Slim

Tags: c#, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

How do I specify data to be used in each of my test cases?

i.e. I wish to use one table to setup some data and then run a bunch of tests against that data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking at [Gojko](http://gojko.net/FitNesse/book/ch05.html) and their suggestion is to create a singleton that you invoke at the beginning of your test page.  Here's an example of the FitNesse edit:

```
!|import         |
|Demo1.Containers|
|Demo1.Fixtures  |

!|SUT         |
|Get Practice?|
|$practice=   |
```

And my C# code (SUT -> System Under Test is a basic Singleton:

```
public class SUT
{
    private static Practice _practice = null;
    public static Practice getPractice()
    {
        if (_practice == null)
        {
            _practice = new Practice();
        }
        return _practice;
    }
}
```

My other classes that I'm testing use that singleton to get their data.

```
    public class AddDoctorToPractice
    {
        private Practice practice = SUT.getPractice();
        ...
```

I hope that helps.